# Splitting a string multiple ways into an array with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to split a string that has `""` and spaces.

---

My input would be:

```js
'!command "string one" so "string two" st "string three" st'
```

And the array should be:

```js
array[0] = "string one"
array[1] = "so"
array[2] = "string two"
array[3] = "st" // ect....
```

Right now this my code, which takes the command and then the arguments behind it:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: share an example of the expected result

Comment: Has absolutely nothing to do with node or discord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression and `.match` either non- `"` characters, or match non-spaces (of which the first character isn't a `"`):

```js
const input = '"string one" so "string two" st "string three" st';
const output = input.match(/\b[^"]+\b|(?!")\S+/g);
console.log(output);
```

Or, to be a bit more robust, match the `"`s too and then `.map`:

```js
const input = '"string one" so "string two" st "string three" st';
const output = input
  .match(/"[^"]+"|\S+/g)
  .map(str => str.startsWith('"') ? str.slice(1, str.length - 1) : str);
console.log(output);
```